# Recursive Function - $f(n)=f(an)+f(bn)+n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

I've got this recursive function $f(n)=f(an)+f(bn)+n$, and I need to find $θ$ on $f(n)$, as $a+b>1$.

Using a recursive tree, I managed to bound it by $n\log(n)$ from the bottom and by $n^2$ from the top, but I can't seen to find the $θ$ bound.

I'd be glad for some help.

Thanks in advance,
Yaron.

Answer (score 2):

Take a peek at Leighton's ["Notes on Better Master Theorems for Divide-and-Conquer Recurrences"](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/doc_view/pid/513611099c8ba4c5b8b878af143641175fe351b0) (1996). This is sadly not formally published anywhere I'm aware of. For a recurrence:
$$
T(n) = g(n) + \sum_{1 \le k \le n} a_k f(b_k n + h_k(n))
$$
where $a_k > 0$ and $0 < b_k < 1$, $h_k(n) = O(n / (\log n)^2)$, and $\lvert g(n) \rvert = O(n^c)$ for some constant $c$. For the typical case of "round up/down to the next integer" $h_k$ this is satisfied.

Compute $p$ such that:
$$
\sum_{1 \le k \le n} a_k b_k^p = 1
$$
then:
$$
T(z)
        = \Theta
            \left(
              z^p \left(
                     1 + \int_1^z \frac{g(u)}{u^{p + 1}} \, \mathrm{d} u
                  \right)
            \right)
$$
in your case, $g(n) = n$, which satisfies the condition.
$$
a^p + b^p = 1
$$
gives $p = 1$, your $g(n) = n$ gives:
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \Theta(n^1(1 + \int_1^n \frac{u}{u^2} \mathrm{d} u)) \\
     &= \Theta(n \log n)
\end{align}

Comment: This is the [Akra-Bazzi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method). Doubt: Why does $p=1$ satisfy $a^p + b^p = 1$?

Comment: @Anant, the details are hidden in a blizzard of integrals in the cited paper. And this is *known* as Akra-Bazzi, but their paper proves a much weaker result.